# SPARK : Increasing the number of DRIVER MEMORY can decrease the performance?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am tuning an application running on Spark 1.5.2. I ran 2 times the exact same script, but with different driver.memory parameter.

- First time : driver.memory = 15g / Execution time : 6,1h
- Second time : driver.memory = 2g / Execution time : 5,7h

The goal of the script is only making join on a same table and iterate on it with a newer table, before saving it in a Hive table.

I though the more memory we give, the better it is. But this idea is kind of false according to the tests... Is really the driver memory responsible of it ? Or is  the process which run +/- randomly ...?

Comment: Increasing memory in Java can severely affect both benchmarks and overall performance. Full GCs on the driver will pause all driver-cluster massaging and might delay fetching results. There are more details involved, but don't know how these apply to pySpark

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if your driver is running on standalone machine(where no executor is running). Try to increase driver memory if you are using collect/take actions otherwise increase executor memory for better performance.

If you are not using cache, try to increase spark.shuffle.memoryFraction.

See spark doc for more details: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/configuration.html